# Typescript React onChangeHandler type error

Tags: input, onchange, react-typescript

This is the simplified version of my react component. The inputs are renders based on value of `isCase1`. I have a `onChangeHandler` to update `formContent`.

```
...

interface AddressForm {
  name: string;
  address: string;
}
interface PhoneForm {
  name: string;
  phoneNumber: number;
}

const [formContent, setformContent] = useState<AddressForm | PhoneForm | undefined>(
  undefined
);

const onChangeHandler = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  const { name, value } = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
  setformContent({ ...formContent, [name]: value });
};

return (
  <form>
    <input
      type="text"
      name="name"
      value={formContent.name}
      onChange={onChangeHandler}
    />
    {isCase1 ? (
      <input
        type="text"
        name="address"
        value={formContent.address}
        onChange={onChangeHandler}
      />
    ) : (
      <input
        type="number"
        name="phoneNumber"
        value={formContent.phoneNumber}
        onChange={onChangeHandler}
      />
    )}
  </form>
);
```

However, this onChangeHandler is giving me an error saying:

"Argument of type '{} | { name: string; address: string; } | { name: string; phoneNumber: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<AddressForm | PhoneForm | undefined>'.

Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<AddressForm | PhoneForm | undefined>'.ts(2345)"

How can I specify the type in the onChangeHandler to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const [formContent, setformContent] = useState<AddressForm | PhoneForm | undefined | {}>(undefined);
```

Comment: Tried it, but still getting the error...

Comment: Strange, What kind of error are you getting now?

Comment: Argument of type '{ name?: string | undefined; address?: string | undefined; phoneNumber?: number | undefined; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<(AddressForm & PhoneForm) | undefined>'.
  Type '{ name?: string | undefined; address?: string | undefined; phoneNumber?: number | undefined; }'

Comment: is not assignable to type 'AddressForm & PhoneForm'.
    Type '{ name?: string | undefined; address?: string | undefined; phoneNumber?: number | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'AddressForm'.
      Types of property 'name' are incompatible.
        Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
          Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)

Comment: Thanks! No error now.